# Does implementing EMV PIN Bypass entail re-certification?

Tags: point-of-sale, emv

We are already certified for EMV for all four brands. We are planning to implement PIN Bypass functionality and set TVR appropriately(Customer Bypassed PIN). Will this change require re-certifying for all four brands again? we are kind of getting mixed responses from our Acquirer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about device and software certification/legal issues and not about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, most likely: while you were passing MCHIP certification the appropriate tests were not included into test set.

Comment: Best thing to do is get it checked with regional payment scheme contact and also your national regulatory requirements on whether PIN bypass is allowed.
This is also a business call as it increases some risk and thereby chargebacks.
But I feel a certification may not be necessary as the issuers can decline if B3b4 is ON in TVR.
However make sure you do a comfort test on all the payment schemes and make sure the TVR is populated as expected in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure, but I think it does require a re-certification.

Some schemes demand specific test cases with PIN bypass, and those were probably not certified before by your solution as you didn't have it before.